# I think my post was mismarked as spam

Tags: discussion, support, spam, suspensions

I have a question about my Software Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Could H correctly decide that P never halts?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/429944/could-h-correctly-decide-that-p-never-halts)

[This SE meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor) says, a post should be marked as spam only if it promotes a product, service, or similar; and is unsolicited or lacks disclosure of affiliation.

Answer (score 12):

You posted the question exclusively to promote a paper that you wrote and solicit reviews. Promoting your paper is no different than promoting your software product or a service. Treating this as spam seems very appropriate.

Comment: Since there is no issue of any monetary gain it would seem that you are flatly incorrect.  I only want a fair review of my ideas. So far no one has been willing to do that. Everyone begins under the fundamental assumption  that I must be wrong. When they fail to find any error, they simply give up.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor

Comment: @polcott Monetary gain is not a requirement for something to be spam. This isn't a place to get a review of your ideas. This is a place for people to post questions about problems they are having and others to post answers to help solve those problems. Perhaps a discussion board would be more appropriate, but you'd have to invest some time to find a place where sharing your own work for review is acceptable.

Comment: StackExchange has much more qualified reviewers than any other online forum. If you measure my post against the official  stack exchange criteria for spam there is no match. You are apparently the only SE reviewer that has this incorrectly.

Comment: @polcott It doesn't matter if you think that the people here are more qualified than other places, this type of post is not appropriate for this venue. And I'm not the only person who believes your post was spam - it was flagged as such by other users and I handled those flags, so multiple people believe your post doesn't belong here.

Comment: Not sure if the "Spam" rules really apply here (for the dupe on Stackoverflow, my Spam flag was declined), but IMHO the OP's question would probably fit a lot better on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ than on SE.SE or SO.